# Star Wars Battlefront: Do healing streaks increase your trait card level?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

In Star Wars Battlefront, do healing streaks increase your trait card level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as my knowledge goes, the only way to level up your trait is through killstreaks. I've gone on a lot of healing streaks without any trait leveling.